# G++ Hung or Busy?

Tags: c++, g++

I am attempting to compile from the command line on a very slow device (www.raspberrypi.org); however, I am used to IDE's.

My command looks a lot like: `g++ -I/yadayada/include "/path/main.c"`.

However, the only response I seem to get a `>` bar.  It's been sitting there long enough I think it's hung, *but*, I would appreciate it if I could get some output from it at all...

Thanks!

Comment: Try redirecting the output to a file? (Don't forget to redirect stderr too with `&>`, if you do this.) Also, can you perhaps open another terminal window (or use `screen`) and see what `g++` is doing in `top`?

Comment: Oh!  Thank you, but what I meant is that there *is* no output....

Comment: You mean `g++` is completing successfully? What does `echo $?` say the return value was? Were any files (like `a.out`) generated in the current directory?

Comment: No... I mean, I'm sure it's just hung.  I can work around this problem now it seems, but, it'd be nice if I could get some more information out of the compiler, that's all....

Comment: Hmm, very odd. Maybe `g++` is crashing? Does it work with a very minimal main.c (`int main() { return 0; }`)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41297/discussion-between-user1833028-and-cameron)

Comment: Maybe try to run `g++` with `-v` option? Or try something from this list: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html There are some options for debuggin g++ itself.

Comment: Maybe you're running out of memory? Do you have a swap partition or zram?

Comment: Can you cut and paste in the EXACT command line you are trying to run?  The `>` bar typically means there is an open quote (or other special shell character) missing in your command line.